# How to show more than 1 custom taxonomy term or link on a custom post type?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I have created a custom taxonomy called 'tema' and the taxonomy has three terms. I want to show ALL the term links that are related to the current post. Currently I can only get my code to show ONE of the posts taxonomy terms...

I would like the term links displayed via my custom content.php file ("content-home.php") that I use for showing excerpts of my custom posts on my homepage.

Currently I have this code placed in my custom content.php file and it actually works fine but I can only get it to show ONE term:

```
<?php

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'tema');

    foreach($terms as $term) {
           echo '<a href="' . get_term_link($term) . '"><span>' . $term->name . '</span></a>';
    }
?>
```

Can anyone please show me how I get it to show ALL the posts taxonomy term links?

Comment: did you *print_r($terms);* how many you are getting mam ?

Answer (score 0):

In the WordPress Codex you can find:

For get_the_terms:
"Retrieve the terms of the taxonomy that are attached to the post."
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms

For get_terms:
"Retrieve the terms in a taxonomy or list of taxonomies."
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

So, `get_the_terms()` will get the terms (e.g. categories) attached to a post, whereas `get_terms()` will retrieve the terms in a taxonomy (e.g. categories in the category taxonomy). For example, `get_terms( 'category' )` will return all categories that you have added to your WordPress site.

You should use something like this:

```
<?php                   
  $terms= get_terms(array('taxonomy'=>'tema'));
  foreach($terms as $term){
      echo '<a href="' . get_term_link($term) . '"><span>' . $term->name . '</span></a>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: Awesome (y).. super stuff.

Comment: Thanks but then it spits out all three terms on all of my posts. I need it to display only the terms which apply to the specific post. Can you help? :-)

Comment: Then your code should work. Use your code under `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
/*Your code here*/ endwhile; endif; ?>`

Comment: But I can't put the loop inside my content file when it starts with <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>> can I?  When i try to it runs the loop until it times out and the page goes blank.

Answer (score 0):

Try below hook function to get list of taxonomy of particular post id,

```
//Returns All Term Items for "my_taxonomy"
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'my_taxonomy', array("fields" => "all"));
print_r($term_list);
```

*my_taxonomy - replace your taxonomy

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms

Comment: Thanks GNANA but then it prints all the info about the taxonomy term and that is not what I want... It still does not show the terms that are used on the specific post...

Comment: you need that taxonomy used post list ?

Comment: If yes means, try this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66219/list-all-posts-in-custom-post-type-by-taxonomy

Comment: No the opposite: I want to show the taxonomy terms that relates to a given post and it should be inside the specific post. The problem is that I can only get it to show ONE of the related terms. I have a custom post type called 'news' and to this CPT I have made a custom taxonomy called 'tema'. 'tema' has three terms: rehab, urban and detention. If I assign 2 of the terms to the same post my code only shows one of the terms. I hope this makes sense?